# Access Maven property "developers" in application.yml (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I want to have the developer, which is defined in the pom.xml with the  tag to appear in the application.yml after the build process. Somehow it is working with all attributes but developers.

This is in a Spring Boot project, I want the attributes to be filled during the build process.

This is an excerpt of the pom.xml

```
<description>my description</description>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>12345</id>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <email>john@doe.com</email>
    </developer>
</developers>
```

This is in application.yml

```
info:
  description: "@project.description@"
  developer: "@project.developers[0].id@"
```

It works for description, but not for developer. I tried many variations, e.g. ${..}, "@project.developers.0.id". Nothing seems to be working.

If anybody has an idea, I would be very grateful.

Comment: it might just be "@project.developers.developer[0].id@" ?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. @wemu

Comment: that would have been to easy anyway. can't find any example either. the property syntax with the dots translates to .getXXX() - so maybe project.developers.0. - or some variant. maybe the issue tracker contains some hints if this is supported at all

Comment: I came to the conclusion that it isn't supported, because it is a collection. Now I am trying to parse the pom.xml at runtime to get the developers. @wemu

Answer (score 2):

You can read the developer `id` or `email` address or any values from the `pom.xml` with this elegant way:

1. Generate the `build-info.properties` with the default data plus your additional data
2. Read values from this file easily with Spring via the `BuildProperties`.

**pom.xml:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProperties>
                    <developer>${project.developers[0].email}</developer>
                </additionalProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will produce a `build-info.properties` file under the `META-INF` directory with the following content:

```
build.artifact=<artifactId-from-pom>
build.group=<groupId-from-pom>
build.name=<name-from-pom>
build.time=<build-time>
build.version=<version-from-pom>
build.developer=<email-of-the-first-developer-from-pom>
```

**Then you can read values with Spring:**

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private BuildProperties buildProperties;

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI()) {
        return new OpenAPI().info(new Info()
                .title(...)
                .version(buildProperties.getVersion())
                .contact(new Contact().email(buildProperties.get("developer"))));
    }
}
```

To read:

- [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/build-info.html)
- [BuildProperties](http://useof.org/java-open-source/org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties)

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score -3):

Add it on the property and use on pom and property file, example:

```
<properties>
     <team.name>John Doe</team.name>
</properties>
```

Use on developer data:

```
<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>${team.name}</name>
...
```

And in the application use the property:

```
 description: "@team.name@"
```